# Issue in refresh of browser angular2

Tags: angular

I am having issue while refreshing the browser it shows 404 not found error.

I have tried adding
      in index.html but its of no use.
and also
LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy
But it seems to not work.

I am using VS2015 with 4.5 .net framework

This is my app.routes.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { JobBookingComponent } from './component/jobbooking';
import { JobDetailsComponent } from './component/jobbookingdetailscomponent';
import { JPTemplateComponent } from './component/jptemplate.component';


const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/templatejp', pathMatch: 'full' },

{ path: 'template', component: JobBookingComponent },
{ path: 'templatejp', component: JPTemplateComponent },
{ path: 'detail/:templateid', component: JobDetailsComponent }

];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>document.write('<base href="/" />');</script>
<title>Demo</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" />
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/resources/icons/css/font-awesome.min.css" />-->
<!--<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></script>-->

<link href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
<!-- Polyfill for older browsers -->
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
</head>
<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

app.ts

```
import './rxjs-operator';
import { Component, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
<nav>
<a routerLink="/template" routerLinkActive= "active" > Template </a>
  <a routerLink="/templatejp" routerLinkActive= "active" > Templatejp </a>
    </nav>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>`
 })

 export class AppComponent {

  }
```

Please help to resolve the issue
Thanks.

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: While refresh it is showing 404 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the issue was that I was importing PathLocationStrategy need to use HashLocationStrategy
update the (app.module.ts) 
By importing HashLocationStrategy and locationstrategy and adding in providers.

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
declarations: [AppComponent],
imports: [BrowserModule],
providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `<base href="/" />` on your index page instead of adding it dynamically from the script

Answer (score 0):

So, a 404 error means your web server (in this case the development server your running when you build your app) can't find the page. Does your application build without any errors? When its running the console should show a log of the pages being requested and whether they were found (http status 200).

Answer (score 0):

the issue is happening because route cannot be found, use import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core'; Here is a sample code for the routing export:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { JobBookingComponent } from './component/jobbooking';
import { JobDetailsComponent } from './component/jobbookingdetailscomponent';
import { JPTemplateComponent } from './component/jptemplate.component';


const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'templatejp', pathMatch: 'full' },

{ path: 'template', component: JobBookingComponent },
{ path: 'templatejp', component: JPTemplateComponent },
{ path: 'detail/:templateid', component: JobDetailsComponent }

];

@NgModule({
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true });
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```